# "Scanner.nextLine()" in Java does skip, "NoLineFound"-Exception

Tags: java, file, exception, java.util.scanner

The following code reads some data out of a file called *Ergebnisse 00_01*, which i want to be displayed (`System.out.println(..);`). So, some whitespace-lines are missing, some other data is also not printed. At the end, `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found` is showing up, but why? What i am doing wrong?

```
ArrayList<String> singleParts = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    int index = 0;
    scanner = new Scanner( new File("files/Ergebnisse 00_01.txt") );
    while ( scanner.hasNextLine() )  {
        singleParts.add(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.println(index+": "+scanner.nextLine() );
        index++;
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Throwable te) {
    te.printStackTrace();
}
```

The result should be (here without index in front):

```
----------

1.Spieltag 00/01
11.08.2000 - 20:15 Uhr  (7.) Borussia Dortmund 1:0 FC Hansa Rostock (12.)

Herrlich (61.) 1:0

12.08.2000 - 15:30 Uhr  (13.) 1.FC Kaiserslautern 0:1 VfL Bochum (8.)

Buckley (62.) 0:1

12.08.2000 - 15:30 Uhr  (5.) Bayer 04 Leverkusen 2:0 VfL Wolfsburg (15.)

Kirsten (14.) 1:0
Kirsten (24.) 2:0

12.08.2000 - 15:30 Uhr  (1.) SC Freiburg 4:0 VfB Stuttgart (18.)

Dreyer (4.) 1:0
Zeyer (28.) 2:0
Baya (48.) 3:0
Dorn (80.) 4:0
```

Real output:

```
0: 1.Spieltag 00/01
1: Herrlich (61.) 1:0
2: 
3: 12.08.2000 - 15:30 Uhr   (5.) Bayer 04 Leverkusen 2:0 VfL Wolfsburg (15.)
4: Kirsten (24.) 2:0
5: 
6: Baya (48.) 3:0
```

Comment: You're checking if `hasNextLine()` once, but reading `nextLine()` twice.

Comment: Thank you very much! Please make your comment into an answer so i can accept it!

Comment: @GaryKlasen An answer has been provided below to accept. Just sayin :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are calling `scanner.nextLine()` twice but you are only printing it once.
Every time you call `scanner.nextLine()` you advance the scanner to the next line.

Try this:

```
    String next = scanner.nextLine();
    singleParts.add(next);
    System.out.println(index+": "+next );
```